# Power Bi and WebBrowser control

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

It is possible to render a power bi report in a windows form web browser control? I created an html file and added to navigate method but is not working. Also I added the html content to the documenttext property and is not working.

I'm using the embed for customer.. approach but I only get a blank page. This is the code that I pass to the webbrowser control. Do you have a sample using the windows forms project?

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8' />
            <title></title>
            <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js' referrerpolicy='no-referrer'></script>
            <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/powerbi-client/2.19.1/powerbi.min.js' integrity='sha512-JHwXCdcrWLbZo78KFRzEdGcFJX1DRR+gj/ufcoAVWNRrXCxUWj2W2Hxnw61nFfzfWAdWchR9FQcOFjCNcSJmbA==' crossorigin='anonymous' referrerpolicy='no-referrer'></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id='embedContainer'></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                const reportContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
                const accessToken = 'token.....';
                const embedUrl = 'https://xxx.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=0b0fe232.....';
                const embedReportId = '0b0fe232.....';
                const tokenExpiry = '5/20/2022 5:42:13 PM';
                const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
                const config = {
                    type: 'report',
                    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                    accessToken: accessToken,
                    embedUrl: embedUrl,
                    id: embedReportId,
                    permissions: models.Permissions.All,
                    settings:
                    {
                        filterPaneEnabled: true,
                        navContentPaneEnabled: true
                    }
                };
                const report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);

            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks,
Ev

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There are a number of approaches you can consider.

[Power BI Secure Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure) just uses an IFrame and the desktop user will need to authenticate to Power BI.  Minimally generate the embedding link from Power BI

[image]

and embed it in an a static HTML page like this:

```
<html>
    <iframe title="Some Report" 
            style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none"  
            src="https://xxx.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=d12ecc27-a855-4b27-9..." 
            frameborder="0" 
            allowFullScreen="true">
    </iframe>
</html>
```

Or you can build and register full web app to do embedding using either the [Embed For Your Customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core), or the [Embed For Your Organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization?tabs=net-core) workflow.  This adds a [javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/) to control and interact with the embedded reports from your hosting application.